# Error Django con Postgres

Tags: django

no logro conectar mi DB de Postgrest con Django, al ejecutar "manage.py migrate" se muestra un error "SyntaxError: invalid syntax". Tengo instalado:
Django 2.1.7
psycopg2 2.6.2
psql 9.2.4
Python 3.7.2

```
    (test19) C:\proyecto_django\Test>manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\proyecto_django\Test\manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\PROYECTOS\src\ambientes\test19\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\PROYECTOS\src\ambientes\test19\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\PROYECTOS\src\ambientes\test19\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\PROYECTOS\src\ambientes\test19\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\PROYECTOS\src\ambientes\test19\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\python372\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\PROYECTOS\src\ambientes\test19\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\PROYECTOS\src\ambientes\test19\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\PROYECTOS\src\ambientes\test19\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 101, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\PROYECTOS\src\ambientes\test19\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 305, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\PROYECTOS\src\ambientes\test19\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 203, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\PROYECTOS\src\ambientes\test19\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\PROYECTOS\src\ambientes\test19\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 202, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\PROYECTOS\src\ambientes\test19\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\python372\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\PROYECTOS\src\ambientes\test19\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 20, in <module>
    import psycopg2 as Database
  File "C:\PROYECTOS\src\ambientes\test19\lib\site-packages\psycopg2-2.6.2-py3.7-win32.egg\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 104
    connection_factory=None, cursor_factory=None, async=False, **kwargs):
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Problamente se deba a que `async` es una palabra reservada para esa versión de Python 3.

Comment: Yo uso Django 2.1 y Psycopg 2.7.4 sin problemas. Porque ejecutas la sentencia como manage.py migrate? Yo uso "python manage.py migrate" o "python3 manage.py migrate" si uso linux

Answer (score 1):

César y Franco, muchas gracias!
El error se presentaba por la versión del Psycopg de acuerdo a lo comentado por César. Actualicé la versión y funcionó.

Franco, la sentencia "manage.py migrate" es equivalente a "python manage.py migrate"; así la ejecuté satisfactoriamente.